# Текстура bump в blender отображается точками

Tags: blender, текстура

Текстура bump отображается точками (изображение прилагаю). Такое ощущение что присутствуют лишние пиксели, но их нет. Пробовал пересоздать текстуру, результат тот же.[image: скриншот]

[image: PNG]

Comment: JPG? Похоже на артефакты jpg

Comment: Да JPEG, пробовал PNG, но в нем на месте надписи частично появляется квадрат

Comment: PNG c прозрачностью видимо? Прозрачный цвет интерпретируется в png как черный

Comment: Да с прозрачностью, сейчас попробую убрать ее

Comment: Да, спасибо. получилось)